# How to serialize QColor, QSize, QPoint, for QXmlStreamWriter/Reader

Tags: c++, xml, qt, serialization, qt4

I am saving off some item characteristics, and I want to serialize them to XML for writing to a file and/or saving in a database.  However, I don't see any obvious way to serialize `QColor`, `QSize`, and `QPoint`.  What is the right way to serialize `QColor`, `QSize`, and `QPoint` to a `QString` for writing to XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
QDataStream out(&buffer);
out << "your QColor, QSize, or QPoint";
```

`buffer.buffer()` then returns a QByteArray with your serialized QColor, QSize, or QPoint.
This should be suitable to be written into your xml file. To be on the safe side, you should convert the content of the QByteArray to base64 or make otherwise sure, that it contains only allowed chars for xml.

Yes, I am sure that's not what you were hoping for, but a direct serialization into a QXmlStreamWriter is, as far as I know, not possible.

Comment: Serializing to binary and then Converting to Base64 is a great idea!  Thank you!

Comment: -1: This is not such a great idea since it **utterly fails to leverage the XML data model**. You're stuffing a binary blob into XML - something that can't be searched/extracted by standard XML processing tools. If you want to store binary blobs, don't use XML, it's pointless. Similarly, storing XML in a database is almost always pointless as well.

Comment: This is nonsense, what you are saying. Of course, it is not wrong, but it isn't right either. It just depends on the concrete requirements. If Freedom_Ben is happy with this proposal, when he does not need to search/extract, this is the a simple way to accomplish, what he asked. If not, he can alwas use peppe's method.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a builtin way. You could "mimic" what QDataStream for those types does -- [it's documented](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/datastreamformat.html). Just remember that QDataStream is a binary format, while XML is not. So, for instance:

- QColor: serialize the color spec (as a string?), then the components (according to that spec):

  ```
  <color spec="cymk"><cyan>0.024451</cyan><yellow>...</color>
  ```
- QSize: serialize the width and the height

  ```
  <size><width>2421</width><height>624</height></size>
  ```

  or maybe

  ```
  <size width="2421" height="624" />
  ```
- QPoint: serialize the X / Y coordinates
- QString: ...just write it?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  It is good to keep in mind that `QDataStream` is binary.  I took the QDataStream output and Base-64ed it into a string